# Setting up a reverse proxy without opening an incoming port (only an outgoing port) on the firewall

Tags: networking, centos, proxy, reverse-proxy

I've received an unusual request to which I'm not sure there's a solution.

My client wants to host a web application on Machine A, and have it accessed only by visiting a URL of the publicly-accessible Machine P.

Normally, a reverse proxy should suffice, but there's one extra, arguably unnecessary complication: my client doesn't want to open the web application's port on Machine A's firewall -- not even restricted to Machine P's IP address.  But they're fine with Machine A making a connection to Machine P if Machine A is somehow making an *outgoing* connection.

Is there any existing software I can leverage to set up reverse proxy in such a way that Machine A initializes the connection-- connecting to a port bound on Machine P-- after which Machine P is able to reverse-proxy incoming web requests to Machine A?

Both machines are running CentOS (6 or 7), and I have full control to install any software I find on them.  The only restriction is that I can't open any incoming ports on Machine A's public-facing firewall (with Machine P considered "public" despite being, from my perspective, a trusted machine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to realise, any solution you use is a lot worse then opening up the firewall on machine B to allow machine A.

You could create an ssh tunnel from machine B to machine A, and then use that.  The syntax would eb something like  (from Machine A):

> ssh -R 8081:localhost:8080 user@machineb

This will allow people to connect to localhost:8081 on machineA to connect to port 8080 on machineb.

It is not a great idea in this case because you loose visibility of the traffic making debugging harder, and needlessly encrypt it through SSH.

There are, of-course, a number of other ways to do the same thing - like, for example, setting up an OpenVPN tunnel between the 2 machines.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good solution given the restriction.